# Custom Authentication with Custom User in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I know there is documentation for this question here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/, however I need some clarification on my use case.

I basically have an api that I created. What this api does is submit user form data to an external url, and once submitted, the data is saved to that external urls database.

I can then get a specific user through another api call. The user is returned as an object. Now I am trying to log that user in on my end using the django.contrib.auth through my system but what I have isn't working.

Here is my process:

A. I added a custom authentication backend to my settings.py file

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS =(
    'new_app.backends.SettingsBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

B. In my new_app's backend file, I have the following code:

```
class SettingsBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
            if username and password:
                user = api.get_user()
                #add pk to user object to satisfy django error warning
                user.pk = user.unique_field
                return user
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            if self.user.pk == user_id:
                return self.user
        except:
            return None
```

In a signin view, I am trying to log the user in using this:

```
def login_user(request, username, password):
    from django.contrib import auth 
    if not username and password:
        raise ValueError("Invalid username and password")

    auth_user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if auth_user is None:
        raise ValueError("Invalid username and password")

    auth.login(request, auth_user)
    return auth_user
```

I get the error saying:

```
'api.get_user()' object has no attribute 'save'
```

The error is occuring on the `auth.login(request, auth_user)` line.

I think the reason is because the django.contrib.auth thinks my user object is a django model. So, the question is how should I tackle this to make it work given my scenario? Thanks for the time.

Comment: have you stated the changed user model in settings?

Comment: @RA123 thanks for the response. I didn't because this is not a typical django user model so I thought that wasn't neccessary. I feel like I am close but need to perhaps not use django.contrib.auth and make my own auth method but that's where I need some guidance.

Comment: Please first set AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_custom.MyUser' if you aren't using django's user model

Comment: @RA123 thanks but that doesn't work. This is a user object that is gotten from an api call, there is no custom user model that i have in my app models file. I'm not even using a models file since everything is gotten from an external database. I hope it makes sense

Comment: You cannot use login method, as it will look for the user id in whatever user database is defined (default if not) to create/continue sessions. Therefore it needs a user model class.

Comment: @RA123 thanks. So basically what you are suggesting is that after I bring in the user object from my api call, I should just save it in a user model just for ease of access? It sounds like this might be the less strenuous approach because if not I would need to write my own login method and create a class similar to django.contrib.auth.

Comment: Exactly. Either you save the user somewhere and point that to django or override all the user related features (wherever the user object from database via model class is needed) and maybe give up on some of django's native features. like in this case 'Sessions'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at django subtleties (as it's been a while I left django for microframeworks).

That said, if I were you, what I'd do is to make sure that whatever `api.get_user()` is returning, implement whatever API django is expecting from that object, which means starting with an empty `save()` method on it.

But I'd also do standard django stuff, like @RA123 suggests in a comment, by setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` up.

Comment: thanks for the input! Looking into that now. Will post answer when I have it working.